# React Native - Android - "Error: Duplicate Resources" - Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'

Tags: android, react-native, ssl-certificate

Due to an SSL cert config issue with our backend, we've had to bundle some SSL certs into

`/android/app/src/main/res/raw/*.der`

It seems since doing so, we now get issues at one of the final tasks of the android release build

`:app:mergeBetaReleaseResources` (we have 2 flavors, `beta` & `prod` so that's why theres the  `beta` in the task name - essentially treat it as a normal release.

Just for context;

Each build is pre cleaned, so there won't be any lingering assets/files in the build directories from previous attempts.

Running a debug build works fine, it's only when trying to build a release version.

So there are various images that the error stack mentions, but I notice (as an example) that the paths are as follows;

`[drawable-mdpi-v4/image_name] /android/app/build/generated/res/react/betaRelease/drawable-mdpi/image_name.png`

`[drawable-mdpi-v4/image_name] /android/app/build/generated/res/react/beta/release/drawable-mdpi/image_name.png: Error: Duplicate resources`

All of a sudden the build is creating separate paths for the same image (duplicated from the assets folder within `src`).

Does anyone know why adding files within a `raw` directory has suddenly caused this issue, and secondly, if theres a build task called "merge resources" why 2 files of the same name, extension (and file size) aren't "merged", ie. one of them discarded, and why it fails the build? From previous answers to a similar question on SO, the accepted answers is "just `rm -rf` your /drawable & /raw directories" but give no context or reasoning behind it.

I'm happy to add more context to this question if you ask for it. Sadly the current accepted answer of "remove directories" can't be the answer for us as we need the ssl certs to communicate with our apis (raw directory, unless these can be stashed somewhere else?) and our drawable directories contain the various bootsplash/splash screen & app icon assets. Any help getting a step forward is appreciated.